# Auto activation triggers for C/C++ in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

I want set the auto activation trigger for a-zA-Z  along with '.' , '->','::'. The last three are provided by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an option in Eclipse Juno C++.